# Equivalent of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Define $( \mathbb R^n, m) $ as a metric space such that $ m=\max \{ | x_i - y_i |:   i=1...n \} .$

And  also $(\mathbb R^2, d) $ as  another metric space such that $d=  \sum_{i=0}^n | x_i - y_i | .$

Question asks: are these metrics equivalent?

I know l should show the equivalent of induced topologies or  $\tau_m $ = $ \tau_d $.

So l should pick an open ball from $ \tau_m$ and show that this open ball is open in $\tau_d $. 
But doesn't look like these basis balls are equivalent,  as one of them is in $\mathbb R^2$ and the other is in $\mathbb R^n$ . Could you please evaluate my approach?

The second question is , what if l change the second metric to ( $\mathbb R^n$, d)?

Then $\mathcal B_\epsilon ^m (x) $ should be open in $\tau_d $.

In this case, what can l do to show these basis balls are open in both topologies?

Comment: I cannot understand your second question: To which metric is $d$ changed?

Comment: @tampis d is charged to ($\mathbb R^n $, d)

Comment: One way to show equivalence of metrics $d1,d2$: For a point $p$ and $\{i,j\}=\{1,2\}$  and $r>0$ show  there exists $s>0$ such that $B_{dj}(p,s)\subset B_{di}(p,r)$.

Comment: @user288280 What is the definition of $d$ in the second question? From the word "change" I deduce that it is not the metric $d$ defined in your first sentence...

Comment: @tampis l just edited the second question ... sorry for that

Comment: Yes the metrics is first sentence is (R^2, d)... but in second question it is (R^n, d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the first question:* $(\mathbb R^n, m)$ and $(\mathbb R^2, d)$ are only be equivalent metric spaces iff $n=2$ because the underlying vector space need to be the same. For $n=2$ see the following paragraph...

*For the second question:* Your metrics are defined by [p-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) and because your vector space is real-valued and finite the metrics are equivalent. See [Any two norms equivalent on a finite dimensional norm linear space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286834/any-two-norms-equivalent-on-a-finite-dimensional-norm-linear-space) why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. .. is there any other way to show it by open balls on both metric spaces for second question?  I mean not using the p - norms

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend to show that the underlying norms are equivalent...